# How to do an One time install of an OS in Virtual box Using a USB

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, installation

I have a USB stick with Kali Linux in it. I want to use it in VirtualBox. I am able to boot from the USB stick in a normal session but not from within VirtualBox.

I need to install Kali once from the USB stick into VirtualBox so I can use it whenever I need it in VirtualBox without needing to plug in the USB stick each time.

I found some documentation, but they were all on booting and using and not about permanently installing.  So I am unable to figure out what to do.  I have searched a lot but found nothing that helps. So my question is, is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: well how do you install it normally outside a vm? boot from usb and install it?

Comment: yes. but in vm i am unable to do like that. i made a virtual disk and then tried booting but in booting order i noticed no usb listed

Comment: so your problem is you can't figure out how to boot from USB. So, talking about kali or linux or whatever isn't that relevant, it's booting off USB you can't do.

Comment: alright. but why usb is not listed in boot order in my vm?

Comment: Information needed. Show a message screen or an error you are experiencing. There are other ways to install an OS in Virtual Box. You can run an .iso file from your computer and it should give you the install screen.

Comment: @allinone1915 You're not trying to boot an installer right? Why not just move the VHD off the USB? Or are you trying to boot the installer (or a live CD?)?

Comment: I don't think virtualbox does USB boot

Comment: Do you have access to a Kali ISO file? That would be the easiest way to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i figured it out.

---

## How to do an One time install of an OS in Virtual box Using a USB

If you just have a live USB and want to use that for creating a VM then this is just for you!

### Step 1

Just like on a real PC to install an OS from a USB, the first thing to do is to boot from the USB stick. In *VirtualBox* this feature is not directly available. But you can do the same in an indirect way as described in this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604889/mingw32-curl-on-windows-7-error-undefined-reference-to-imp-curl-global-init) (thanks to @barlop).

### Step 2

Now you are able to boot from a USB in *VirtualBox*. The next step is to add an additional Virtual Hard Disk to the Virtual Machine you created in *Step 1*.

- To do this Go to Settings->storage and select Controller:SATA.
- Click the icon adjacent to it to add a Virtual Hard Disk.
- Create a new Virtual Hard Disk with about 25GB size by proceeding through the prompts.
- Then click *ok* to close the Settings window.

Now you had added another Virtual Physical Storage device to your virtual machine.

### Step 3

Now Boot from your USB and install the Operating System.

Note:if some thing poped up saying no bootable media then it is likely that the VM tried to boot using the newly created HDD. You just need to reset the VM by pressing Host+R and then press F12.
Now you will be presented with a list of options to boot. There is no option saying Boot from USB. But it is rather given as Hard disk1,2,... In my case my USB was listed as Hard disk2. So i choose Hard disk2.

Now you can use your live USB and do the installation steps. When the installation ask you to select the hard disk select the one we created in *step 2* (You can figure this out by looking at their size. The one i created was 25GB). Then continue the installation procedure normally.

### Step 4

Now its time to remove the USB attached to the virtual machine. 
For this again go to Settings->Storage. Select the USB Hard Disk and click the remove icon. Then click *ok*.

***Congratulations...*** Now you can use your OS anytime from virtual box without the need of USB stick.  ***Enjoy...***

Answer (score 0):

You should first make a copy of the install USB,

```
   dd if=/dev/sdb of=/path/to/empty/folder/kali.iso
```

then create the new VM by loading this image onto the VirtualBox DVD reader.

Here I have assumed that your USB stick is /dev/sdb, and that you have **not** mounted it (this is very important).

Comment: Would that only work for an ISO that is a hybrid?

Comment: And why should he make a copy of the install USB with dd, when he can surely download "kali.iso" ?  And your dd of the USB which can be replaced by downloading the ISO, is actually just a step towards loading a DVD ISO so I am not sure that it answers the question.

Comment: @barlop It fully answers the question. There is no need of extra software, extra download time or bandwidth consumption. As a matter of fact, your proposed solutions are either tentative (n.2) or needlessly complicated.

Comment: I'm sure he downloaded the ISO anyway in order to make the USB.  The dd step makes it look like you're adding some USB element to it addressing booting from USB when really you're not really - especially considering that if he already has the ISO since he downloaded it to make the USB,then copying it from the USB to remake the ISO is unnecessary.And if he hadn't made the USB then he'd have to download the ISO still anyway.step of recovering an iso lost after making the usb.Your solution is purely booting from a DVD ISO as the goal,but with an intermediate step that may or may not be necessary

Comment: I doubt his problem is that he lacks the bandwidth to download the ISO that he already downloaded to make the USB, and he lost the ISO. And now he doesn't know how he can get the ISO again. I think the best you can say for your solution, is forget USB just boot the ISO from DVD (and if he hasn't lost the ISO then your dd is a smokescreen).

Comment: I downloaded the ISO file and then some how i lost it(yeah, i messed things up!) after making my USB. I would really love to get my ISO back rather than download it again. Anyway, i already did the method 2 of @barlop and that's the way i boot from USB. I am now trying to install to a second virtual hard disk from USB  so that i can use Kali without the USB. And now i am stuck at another problem. GRUB is not installing. I tried the steps fro google but i failed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the following methods.. But they came up pretty easily in Google once you know what your problem is. Your problem is as I told you. Booting off USB in VirtualBox. Nothing to do with installing an OS or any particular OS.

And it's clear from google, that Virtualbox doesn't have a boot from USB option. That's your problem, that's why for example USB doesn't come up as an option for booting when you hit F12(as you suggest you noticed in comment). And obviously people have run into this problem and come up with some ways around it. The ways come up easily in google and I was hoping somebody that had done it would post an answer.

**Method 1**
One way is to set some options in VirtualBox, then use a linux distro called Plop and that is what Britec does here in this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSS1bOF7sDA    He is a reliable clear guy and he demonstrates it. It looks like straight-forward use of Plop. People did it also when for some reason a computer (even aside from virtual machines) wouldn't boot USB.

**Method 2**
Another way is apparently you can enable some rather hidden feature of virtualbox

http://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/

for example it involves running this command with # for the disk  `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename C:\usb.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive#`  that command is also unique enough to be easily googlable. I don't want to include the whole method they use here, when I haven't tried it myself, but there's a link there.